# Convert Pandas dataframe to Sparse Numpy Matrix directly

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I am creating a matrix from a Pandas dataframe as follows:

```
dense_matrix = np.array(df.as_matrix(columns = None), dtype=bool).astype(np.int)
```

And then into a sparse matrix with:

```
sparse_matrix = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(dense_matrix)
```

Is there any way to go from a df straight to a sparse matrix?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`df.values` is a numpy array, and accessing values that way is always faster than `np.array`.

```
scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(df.values)
```

You might need to take the transpose first, like `df.values.T`. In DataFrames, the columns are axis 0.

Comment: But this is suppose to generate a memory copy, isn't it? As df.values is essentially returning a dense matrix, and cast to csr_matrix handle. It doesn't work for large matrix.

Comment: No, if I understand correctly `df.values` does not make a copy.

Comment: Another way would be to do e.g. df.replace(0, np.nan).to_sparse(), which results to a sparse DataFrame though, not a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix ...

Comment: df.values creates a dense matrix if df is a SparseDataFrame. Impracticable for large dataset.

Comment: If you want to convert nans to sparse, then you have to do fillna first and then convert.

Comment: @Stan any solution in case of very large dataset ?

Comment: And btw. OP asked for a 'direct' solution. You are converting dataframe to numpy array and then csr_matrix. You are literally densifying the dataframe, creating 'object's by converting Nan's inside a dataframe. Am I missing something here? Why is this an accepted answer? I don't understand.

Comment: Now I guess I understand. Since df.values doesn't return a copy, this is actually a direct conversion?

Comment: This does not work because `df.values` is returning a regular numpy matrix.

Comment: See solution below please.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do it without converting to dense en route:
`csr_sparse_matrix = df.sparse.to_coo().tocsr()`

Comment: I got this error: `AttributeError: Can only use the '.sparse' accessor with Sparse data.` I think pandas does not allow to run it directly.

Comment: `df` has to be a sparse data frame. Convert dense data frame to sparse one via:`sparse_df = df.astype(pd.SparseDtype("float64",0)`

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

csr_matrix = csr_matrix(df.astype(pd.SparseDtype("float64",0)).sparse.to_coo())
```

Explanation:

`to_coo` needs the `pd.DataFrame` to be in a sparse format, so the dataframe will need to be converted to a sparse datatype: `df.astype(pd.SparseDtype("float64",0))`

After it is converted to a COO matrix, it can be converted to a CSR matrix.