# How to convert dask dataframe to scipy csr matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix, dask

**TLDR:** I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459536/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-sparse-numpy-matrix-directly) but it breaks the mentality of lazily evaluating the dask collections. Converting lazily evaluated `dask.dataframe` to `array` with `.values` is problematic (memory-wise). So, how can I convert dask dataframe to `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` without first converting dataframe to array?

**Complete Problem:**
I have 3 dask dataframes. One of them has text features, one with numerical and one with categorical features. I am vectorizing the dataframe with text features using `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer` which is returning a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`. I need to concatenate 3 dataframes into one (horizontally). But they have different `dtype`s. I also `dask_ml.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer`. It returns lazily evaluated `dask.array` but `.compute()` is returning `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`. Without `.compute()` when I try to convert it to `dask.dataframe` as below:

```
import dask.array as da
import dask.dataframe as dd
.
.
.
# Here the fitting the dask.dataframe, result is  lazily evaluated dask.array
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
print(X.compute())
X = dd.from_dask_array(X)
print(X.compute())
```

`X = vectorizer.fit_transform(X)` returns:

```
dask.array<_transform, shape=(nan, 1000), dtype=float64, chunksize=(nan, 1000), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
```

First `print(X.compute())` returns a csr_matrix:

```
  (0, 73)   2.0
  (0, 95)   3.0
  (0, 286)  1.0
  (0, 340)  2.0
  (0, 373)  3.0
  (0, 379)  3.0
  (0, 387)  1.0
  (0, 407)  2.0
  (0, 421)  1.0
  (0, 479)  1.0
  (0, 482)  3.0
  (0, 515)  1.0
  (0, 520)  1.0
  (0, 560)  4.0
  (0, 596)  1.0
  (0, 620)  4.0
  (0, 630)  1.0
  (0, 648)  2.0
  (0, 680)  1.0
  (0, 721)  1.0
  (0, 760)  3.0
  (0, 824)  4.0
  (0, 826)  12.0
  (0, 880)  2.0
  (0, 908)  1.0
  : :
  (10, 985) 1.0
  (11, 95)  3.0
  (11, 171) 4.0
  (11, 259) 4.0
  (11, 276) 1.0
  (11, 352) 3.0
  (11, 358) 1.0
  (11, 436) 1.0
  (11, 485) 1.0
  (11, 507) 3.0
  (11, 553) 1.0
  (11, 589) 1.0
  (11, 604) 1.0
  (11, 619) 3.0
  (11, 625) 2.0
  (11, 719) 1.0
  (11, 826) 6.0
  (11, 858) 2.0
  (11, 880) 3.0
  (11, 908) 1.0
  (11, 925) 2.0
  (11, 930) 4.0
  (11, 968) 1.0
  (11, 975) 1.0
  (11, 984) 4.0
```

the `X = dd.from_dask_array(X)` returns:

```
Dask DataFrame Structure:
                   0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9        10       11       12       13       14       15       16       17       18       19       20       21       22       23
```

Second `print(X.compute())` returns the error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 1), indices imply (6, 1000)
```

So, I can't also convert a csr_matrix to dask.dataframe.

> **UPDATE:** I've just realized that using `.values` on a `dask.dataframe` is actually returning a lazily evaluated
>   `dask.array`. This is still not something I want but at least it is
>   not returning a solid dataframe or array on my local machine.

Comment: I'm confused.  Which way is the conversion going?  The start says `dask to csr`, the end `csr to dask`.  Seems that `vectorizer` is successfully creating a `csr` matrix.

Comment: @hpaulj I am sorry for the confusion. In the end, I tried to explain the actual reason for me trying to convert the dask dataframes to CSR matrices. And the actual reason is that there is no way to receive the vectorized data as a dataframe. The vectorizer only returns a CSR matrix. And I also can't convert the CSR matrix to the dask dataframe. I thought it would be easier to convert a dataframe to a sparse format. That's why the TLDR section asks that question.

Comment: `csr_matrix` shows inputs that you can use to make such a matrix.  The simplest is to just provide a `numpy` array, from which it extracts the nonzero elements.  You can provide the nonzero elements directly, usually in the form of 3 arrays (in effect the list of tuples that the `csr` printout shows).

Comment: Yes, you are right about the simplest way. But densifying the data is also a costly way. That's why I said; "I am aware of this question but it breaks the mentality of lazily evaluating the dask collections." And the question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459536/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-sparse-numpy-matrix-directly Currently, all of my computations are in a cluster of machines running distributed across them.

Comment: @hpaulj do you think converting a CSR to dataframe would be easier in this case?

Comment: One way or other you have to specify all the nonzero elements of the matrix.  The use of sparse matrix format just allows you to skip the zeros.  This sort of conversion makes most sense when the proportion on nonzeros is 10% or less.

Comment: Well... No luck eh? Then I'm gonna wait for dask to implement sparse dataframes as pandas did. And I will wait for someone to come up with a magical solution. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Best possible way is to actually convert it to csr matrix and make it dense.

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix


dd.from_dask_array(X.map_blocks(lambda x: csr_matrix(x).todense()))
```