# one hot encoded sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding

I want to create one hot encoded  features as sparse matrix. I am trying to use `pd.get_dummies` with sparse flag set to True as given below.

```
X = df.iloc[:, :2]
y = df.iloc[:, -1]
X = pd.get_dummies(X, columns = ['id', 'video_id'], sparse=True)
```

But this does not seem to give expected results. All I get is one hot encoded matrix but not CSR matrix.
what is correct  way to create one-hot-encoded sparse matrix?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the sparse matrix you can use `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` as described here: [Convert Pandas dataframe to Sparse Numpy Matrix directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459536/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-sparse-numpy-matrix-directly)

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy

test_df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10), columns = ['category'])

scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(pd.get_dummies(test_df).values
                       )
```

Output

```
<10x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

---

Setting `sparse = True` has to do with types of objects (`np.array` vs `SparseArray`) used internally to produce the output (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

> **sparse**:
> Whether the dummy-encoded columns should be backed by a SparseArray (True) or a regular NumPy array (False).

If you set `sparse = True` it accelerates your code several times:

- Getting dummies with `sparse = True`

```
%timeit pd.get_dummies(test_df.category, sparse=True)
```

Output

```
2.21 ms ± 117 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

- Getting dummies with `sparse = False`

```
%timeit pd.get_dummies(test_df.category, sparse=False)
```

Output

```
454 µs ± 18.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```